# VB Remove blocks of text in textfile

Tags: vb.net, file, text, block, edit

Recently switched to vb after my time in C# and simple question using sytemIO. My predecessor wrote a package that generated error logs to a text file. The following is a sample:

---

```
2017-10-20 15:30:11.481
CmsMonitorService.exe, CmsMonitorService.UpdateCmsOffLine
OffLineUpdater error: Getting list of files stored on the off-line vault.
------------------------------
2017-10-20 15:31:11.547
CmsMonitorService.exe, CmsMonitorService.UpdateCmsOffLine
OffLineUpdater error: Creating folder 'OffLineUpdates' (it may already exist checkHost)
   at CmsMonitorService.CmsMonitorService.UpdateCmsOffLine(Object[] Args)
------------------------------
2017-10-20 15:31:11.547
CmsMonitorService.exe, CmsMonitorService.UpdateCmsOffLine
OffLineUpdater error: Creating folder
------------------------------
```

---

But this is killing the machines. What the code currently does when it is writing is to removed the contents line by line which is painfully slow. It uses the following:

```
Do
 If allLines.Count = 0 Then
    Exit Do
 ElseIf allLines(0).StartsWith("-----") Then
    allLines.RemoveAt(0)
     Exit Do
 Else
    allLines.RemoveAt(0)
 End If
Loop
```

There can be thousands of these (they are at various locations).

What I had wanted to do is find a way of removing the blocks bewteen the  dashes.

Thanks for any ideas everyone.....

Gareth

Comment: Sorry guys... the post got very messed up in posting it. Tyring to re-do it...

Comment: If you store the entire contents in a single `String` then you can use `IndexOf` to find the first and second occurrences of your series of dashes and then remove the substring in between. What might actually be most efficient is to create a `String` and a `StringBuilder` and work backwards. By that I mean call `LastIndexOf` on the `String` to find the last and second last occurrences, then call `Replace` on the `StringBuilder` to remove that substring. Do the same again for the second last and third last occurrences and continue until there are no more occurrences.

Comment: Thank you J... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of the solution I described in my comment above:

```
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "keep line 1" & Environment.NewLine &
                "keep line 2" & Environment.NewLine &
                "----------" & Environment.NewLine &
                "remove line 1" & Environment.NewLine &
                "remove line 2" & Environment.NewLine &
                "----------" & Environment.NewLine &
                "keep line 3" & Environment.NewLine &
                "keep line 4" & Environment.NewLine &
                "----------" & Environment.NewLine &
                "remove line 3" & Environment.NewLine &
                "remove line 4" & Environment.NewLine &
                "----------" & Environment.NewLine &
                "keep line 5" & Environment.NewLine &
                "keep line 6" & Environment.NewLine
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(s)

        Dim endIndex = s.LastIndexOf("----------")

        Do While endIndex <> -1
            Dim startIndex = s.LastIndexOf("----------", endIndex - 1)
            Dim substring = s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 12) 'Add the length of the delimiter and the line break.

            'Remove the delimited block from the StringBuilder.
            sb.Replace(substring, String.Empty, startIndex, substring.Length)

            endIndex = s.LastIndexOf("----------", startIndex - 1)
        Loop

        Console.WriteLine("Before:")
        Console.WriteLine(s)
        Console.WriteLine("After:")
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

It might depend on the specifics of the text as to whether that is more efficient or just using a `String` alone is.